# Can't change Win7 libraries location from Windows Server 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, libraries

I'm having trouble understanding why I can't change the location of my Windows 7 Pro user libraries.

All of my libraries that matter (My Documents, Downloads, Desktop) are located @ **\server1\users\USER**
The Desktop and My Documents libraries are synced with Windows Sync Center and are located @
**\server1\users\USER\My Documents** (& **Desktop**)

On the Windows 7 machine, I can't use the 'move' function normally there. The location field is filled (with locations above) but I can't edit the locations, and there's no move operation.

So, I thought about manually moving them and then changing the registry location of the library, but I'd rather fix whatever permissions problem there is and use the stock libraries tool.

I inherited this Windows Server 2003 environment and it's on the way out. Trying to get everything off of it before I disconnect--this Win7 machine is last and I am so excited.

What am I missing?
Thanks for any help!

EDIT: The reason I posted here on serverfault is I **can** change the library locations for my other libraries (e.g. Contacts or whatever) using the normal Win7 move function found in the Properties of the library.

Comment: I'm assuming these machines are part of a domain? If so have you looked in group policy management?

Comment: Yes, the final Win7 is a part of the domain. Haven't looked at group policy management, but you're my hero for the suggestion. I was looking all over for permissions problem.   
Time to mount another learning curve. Never used GPM.  

Looks like this describes Libraries on the Win7 side: http://kevinjmorse.ca/articles/configuring-windows-7-libraries-using-group-policy-preferences (I'm on Server 2003). 

I'll try GPM tomorrow and update.

Comment: Seriously. This has become a nightmare. 

I can't get Group Policies to update. 8 hours later and I've got nothing. Network isn't available. 

Will hit again tomorrow.